# Passing variable value to cassandra cql statement

Tags: java, cassandra

I have Java code to access and process data in Cassandra. How do I pass a Java variable to Cassandra CQL query written in Java. Here is the code:

My code goes like this:

```
itemname="Item01";

com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement result = 
session.execute("select itemname from demodb.retail_transaction where itemnamw = itemname;");
```

But it gives the following error:

```
no viable alternative at input ';'
```

Comment: You are asking essentially the same question as you did before.

Comment: i guess you are writing the prepared statement wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should bind your variables to the prepared statement like this:

```
    itemname="Item01";
    itemtype="type01";
    com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement result = 
    session.execute("select itemname from demodb.retail_transaction where itemnamw = ? and 
                    itemtype =?;");
    BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
    ResultSet results = session.execute(boundStatement.bind(
              itemname,itemtype));
```